# jquery animate - how to slide in and out on second click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

How to slide out on click and slide in on click using jquery animate? In my code (below) I slide out a div, but cant get it to slide back in based on click. How could I do that? Thanks!

html:

```
<nav>
    <ul id="menu">
        <span id="toggle" class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
        <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span><a>Home</a></li>
        <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><a>About</a></li>
        <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-blackboard"></span><a>Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span><a>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

js:

```
$('#toggle').click(function() {
    if ('#menu'){
        $('#menu').animate({
            //  height: 'toggle'
        }, 1500, function() {
        });
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function named `is` in the jQuery library.
You can use it to check if input is hidden or shown:

```
if ($('#x').is(':visible')) {
    $('#x').slideUp('fast');
} else {
    $('#x').slideDown('fast');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply use [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/).

```
$('#toggle').click(function() {
  $('#menu').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: when I use this, after the first click, the menu slides out and simply disappears after that..